# Redirecting page with Iron-Router

Tags: meteor, iron-router

Currently I am using the accounts packages supplied by Meteor to allow people to sign up for the site I am working on. I want to allow users to have a bio page, whenever I am logged into a particular person a side bar navigation appears with a lot of links one of which says "Bio". I want bio to redirect me from the home page to MY bio page i.e:

```
localhost:3000/ -> localhost:3000/bio/uSerId23453423434
```

Currently write now I am using Iron-Router to do this:

```
...
<li><a href="{{pathFor 'bio'}}">Bio</a></li>
...
```

And in my Router I have:

```
Router.map(function() {
    ...
    this.route('bio',
               {path: '/bio/:_id',
                data: function () { return {_id: Meteor.userId()} }
               });
    ...
```

But when I click on the link I am not redirected anywhere. Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need the parameter _id in your path since you are already using Meteor.userId(). Iron-router won't render if it can't find the _id parameter in the template. Removing it will fix your issue:

```
Router.map(function() {
    ...
    this.route('bio',
               {path: '/bio',
                data: function () { return {_id: Meteor.userId()} }
               });
    ...
```

If you want to keep the path with the _id you should render using {{#with}} to set the data context, for your {{pathFor 'bio'}}

You can view more information at:

- https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/master/DOCS.md#path-functions-and-helpers